# How to use the native browser outline in CSS?

Tags: css, outline

When focusing an input field Chrome and Safari show an outline that can be removed via CSS: `outline: none;`.

I want to display this outline at some other parts to improve usability.
Is there a way to use the native browser outline? 
I only [found](http://www.css3.info/preview/outline/) out how to display a custom one.

Comment: Mainly clickable stuff (like gmail does it in the navigation on the left). But that doesn't really matter for this question does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check out for each browser (via Inspector, F12, or Firebug) what the default setting is. For example in Chrome it is

```
:focus {
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```